# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-kx}\sin x}x\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to evaluate the following integral?

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-kx}\sin x}x\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: In the future, please try to make the title of your questions more informative (I've done so for you now). E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* Furthermore, please do not use excessively big fonts; they come across as shouting.

Answer (score 5):

Differentiating with respect to $k$, one finds an easily computable integral
$$-\int_0^{\infty}e^{-kx}\sin x\,dx=-\frac{1}{1+k^2}$$
Integrating back with respect to $k$ and using that for $k\rightarrow\infty$ the integral is $0$, we obtain
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-kx}\sin x}{x}\,dx=\arctan k^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 4):

You can use Parseval's theorem, i.e.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) g^*(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw \, F(w) G^*(w)$$

where $F$ and $G$ are the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $g$, respectively.  In this case:

$$f(x) = e^{-k x} \theta(x) \implies F(w) = \frac{1}{k-i w}$$

$$g(x) = \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \implies G(w) = \begin{cases}\pi & |w| < 1 \\ 0 & |w| > 1 \end{cases}$$

Then the integral is equal to

$$\frac{\pi}{2 \pi} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dw}{k-i w} = \frac{i}{2} \log{\left( \frac{i k + 1}{i k -1}\right)} = \arctan{\frac{1}{k}} $$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-kx}\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-kx}
\pars{{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{-\ic qx}\,\dd q}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-\pars{k + \ic q}x}\,\,\,\dd x\,\dd q =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}{\dd q \over k + \ic q} =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}{k - \ic q \over q^{2} + k^{2}}\,\dd q
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1/k}{\dd q \over q^{2} + 1} =
\bbx{\arctan\pars{1 \over k}} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Note that the integral is

$$\mathcal{L}\bigg(\frac {\sin(t)}t\bigg)=F(k)$$
Where $\mathcal{L}$
is the Laplace transform operator

You can find the transformation using [power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/370501/734160), which ultimately gives
$$F(k)=\arctan(\frac 1k)$$

Answer (score 0):

[One more option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization):$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(k+y)x}\sin x\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y&=\Im\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(k+y-i)x}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\\&=\int_0^\infty\tfrac{1}{(k+y)^2+1}\mathrm{d}y\\&=[\arctan(k+y)]_0^\infty\\&=\tfrac{\pi}{2}-\arctan k.\end{align}$$